# Is Multihop possible with LoRa?

Tags: lora, lorawan

I have a question regarding how to enable Multihop in LoRa (that is to communicate between two end devices without the LoRaWAN gateway). I have tried doing it using transparent bridging but it won't work.

Although it works with LoRaBlink the issue is flooding. If the number of devices increases the channel utilization as well as the performance goes down rapidly.

Can someone please suggest if there is any other way to do it or how to do it efficiently through LoRaBlink?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the wiki of [Radiohead library](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/), you will find RHRouter and RHMesh under topic **Managers** with the following description:
**RHRouter** Multi-hop delivery of RHReliableDatagrams from source node to destination node via 0 or more intermediate nodes, with manual, pre-programmed routing.
**RHMesh** Multi-hop delivery of RHReliableDatagrams with automatic route discovery and rediscovery.

Answer (score 0):

There are raw LoRa libraries for a mesh network. It's implemented on the Pycom devices, and the library for it is called PyMesh. The technology is based on Thread by Thread groop.